# How do you throw a gas can very high and/or far?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

In *Scavenge* multiplayer mode (and its variants), I've witnessed players throw gas cans much farther and higher than I ever could. I've wasted prescious time running, jumping and left-clicking to throw my gas can high and far, but I've never been able to reproduce the effect...

What am I missing? Is it some arcane combination of mouse movement/clicking? I'm looking for a canonical answer, here, i.e. I want a step-by-step "idiot's guide for dummies" for throwing a gas can high and/or far.

Comment: aim up is what is done traditionally for lobbed weapons

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After testing this, the trick to throwing gas cans involves shoving the gas can as soon as you throw it:

- **Step 1:** Obtain a gas can.
- **Step 2:** Put your crosshairs at least 45° from the ground. I had better results the higher my crosshairs were angled.
- **Step 3:** Move forward, then throw it by pressing <kbd>MOUSE1</kbd>. Don't press <kbd>E</kbd> because you'll just drop it.
- **Step 4:** As soon as the gas can is released in front of you, shove it by pressing <kbd>MOUSE2</kbd>. The shove causes it to launch further.

The timing between <kbd>MOUSE1</kbd> and <kbd>MOUSE2</kbd> is about a tenth of a second. You'll know you did it right if you see the gas can more "flung" into the air (meaning it spins a bunch).

Jumping is optional, as it adds a little height to the throw, but doesn't contribute to distance nearly as much as shoving the can.

A note to those who want to practice this: don't do it on survival. The shove doesn't work on gas cans in this game mode, and after you shove it three times, it explodes into a flamey-gasoliney mess.

To put it in a simplified graph that also doubles as a masterpiece work of art:

[image: Green line is good]

This illustrates the importance of aiming upwards vs aiming towards the horizon.

Comment: I think there is something more to it. After more research, I've found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpbSd3wSo5M), which instructs to do a right click immediately after the left click. I haven't been able to reproduce the effect, though.

Comment: Interesting. Well the question is pretty open ended, as "far" is a relative term. I'll give this a shot tonight to see if I can reproduce it as well.

Comment: @Jubobs that right click after probably makes quite the difference(from reading some forums & from personal experience not doing it). you should transpose the steps into a new answer!

Comment: Just tried it on a listen server. I was able to do it pretty consistently after some practice. I'll revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: Up-vote for your edited answer in combination of one of the greatest drawings I've ever seen. It is a shame it was lost in the edit.

Comment: You convinced me to find a way to re-include it. It's too awesome to be omitted.

Comment: I cannot stress enough how hard this habit is to break after hundreds of scavenge games! I tried more serious survival recently and kept igniting whole piles of cans at the worst possible time. :(

Comment: Can you think of a reason why Valve chose to ignite the gas cans on long-throws when playing in survival / modes other than scavenge? This seems to be a pretty ridiculous decision, a bug even.